# Flask API passing Python list in as string

Tags: javascript, python, json, api, flask

I have a list of strings in my (Python) back-end that I am trying to pass to my front-end (HTML/JS) using Flask. Currently I am using `json.dumps` to pass the list. The problem is that the `<class 'list'>` on the back-end becomes `[object String]` when received on the front-end. I would like to pass the list of strings in as an array of strings, so that I can loop over them and clean the data.

Here is my code:

Python:

```
@app.route("/NegTool", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def NegTool():

    # logic etc... 

    list.append(string)

return render_template('negtool.html', title='ToolHub', mylist=json.dumps(list))
```

HTML/JS:

```
<script> 

var counts = {{ mylist| tojson }};


function testfunc() {

    var val = document.getElementById('textinput').value;

    var counts2 = [];
    var regex = new RegExp('\\s*(?<!\\S)' + val + '(?!\\S)\\s*', 'gi');

    for (const i of counts) {
        var x = i.replace(regex, " ")
        counts2.push(x)
    }

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = counts2;                                         



    };

</script>
```

My question is, how can I receive `mylist` as a proper array of strings such that the above function can process and loop over it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just use key-value paring as Json file usually do. By using a dictionary and recieving a proper Json string, can it properly be parsed and used on the front end

```
json.dumps({'list':list})
```

Just reference it currently on the front end.

Comment: This is not working, It is still coming in as a string, and when I loop over it I get output of individual letters like [t,e,s,t], so it is still a string and not loopable.

Comment: Use JSON.parse() on the string on the front end. Dumps makes it a string the python side and you need to parse it to make it a Json object on the front end side.